# spring webservice server crashes on large attachment

Tags: web-services, spring, attachment

I'm writing a spring webservice server and need to upload a large file from client to server.  So far it's ok until 100MB but after that it crashes with outofmemory error.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:515)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleCharacters(StAXStreamConnector.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:187)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:360)

Here's my config:

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="epost.mojito.ws.wsdl" />
    <property name="mtomEnabled" value="true"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory">
    <description>A message factory to support SOAP 1.2</description>
    <property name="soapVersion">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12" />
    </property>
    <property name="payloadCaching" value="false" />
    <property name="attachmentCaching" value="true" />
    <property name="attachmentCacheThreshold" value="1024"/>
    <property name="attachmentCacheDir" value="D:/mojito attachment test/cache"/>

</bean>
```

Please help!!... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i found this thread which having some tweaks and he manage to send 900MB. Have a look, [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?67669-sending-large-attachments-with-Spring-WS-client)

Comment: Hi, the link is for client sending.  I'm trying to get my server accepting the large file.  thanks

Comment: link is dead, please change it